# Scipy processing large data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a dataset which contain only one column (Pandas Series). Dataset is .dat file, which has about 2 000 000 rows and 1 column (166 MB). Reading this data with *pd.read_csv* takes about 7-8 minutes. This data is a signal, which need to be processed (using `scipy.signal`). So when I process the data I get MemoryError. Is there a way to speed up the loading of the file and **increase the speed of its processing** (`scipy.signal.ellip`) and bypass the memory problem? Thank you in advance.
Loading the data:

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python and programming/Jupyter/Filter/3200_Hz.dat', 
sep='\r\n', header=None, squeeze=True)
```

Data processing (takes about 7 minutes too):

```
b, a = signal.ellip(4, 5, 40, Wn, 'bandpass', analog=False)
output = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
#after that plotting 'output' with plt
```

Example of input data:

```
6954
 25903
 42882
 17820
  3485
-11456
  4574
 34594
 25520
 26533
  9331
-22503
 14950
 30973
 23398
 41474
  -860
 -8528
```

Comment: You're asking multiple things. Taking minutes to read a 166 MB file doesn't sound right at all. I think there's an issue there before you move on to processing the file.

Comment: @roganjosh what can be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. The only thing I can see is `squeeze` so I will look into that. I just don't believe it takes that time to read a file; are you sure you're  just timing the read time?

Comment: @9769953 thank you so much, my fault

Comment: I hope those comments have been deleted in favour of an answer. It's certainly answer-worthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `'\r\n'` as a separator, which means (if I understand correctly) that each line equals a new column. That means you'll end up with millions of columns, and the `squeeze` argument doesn't do anything.

Don't set the `sep` argument (leave it at its default): newlines will separate the records, and `squeeze` will then return it into a `Series`.